What was the 6-bit length instruction(s) in the Intel iAPX 432?
The iAPX 432 was arguably the most complex processor architecture ever and a commercial failure for Intel.  It was a stack machine with no visible general-purpose registers. It had hardware support for object-oriented programming, garbage collection, and multitasking.  The operating system was to be written in Ada.
According to Wikipedia,

The iAPX 432 instructions have variable length, between 6 and 321 bits.  Unusually, they are not byte-aligned, that is, they may contain odd numbers of bits and directly follow each other without regard to byte boundaries.

What were the instruction(s) that needed only 6 bits?  If I am reading the article correctly, such instructions would consist only of a "class" field, with no format field, no operands, and no opcode.

A 6-bit instruction is necessarily order 0 (no operands) and with only a single operation in the class.
The architecture manual lists only these, chapter 11:
Branch 100110
Breakpoint 111111
All branch operations require a 'branch reference' that gives the target of the branch; this is technically not an 'operand'.  It is therefore unclear whether the entire branch operation should be regarded as a 6-bit instruction, or longer.  'Breakpoint' is however complete in 6 bits.
The other order-0 instructions, return and return-and-fault (class 000110) require an opcode part to distinguish them, thus more than 6 bits.

My reading is that branch instructions, including "BRANCH" (BR) take a "branch reference" (a technical term here in this architecture document) which is a field that must be encoded but it is explicitly stated to be not an operand!  (Whatever that distinction is supposed to mean!?) See page 7-22 of the document you link (which is page 131 of the PDF).  So maybe it is considered to be a "6-bit instruction" - or maybe not, leaving BREAKPOINT as the only instruction that is really only 6-bits.  (The various branch instructions are described at page 299 (10-65) in the doc.)

I agree - I read that part later.  I imagine it's "not an operand" in the same way a branch offset is not an operand on a VAX (doesn't follow the convention for an operand specifier).

Updated answer to include branch reference details.

Wouldn't a stack machine have most operations on the accumulator as 0-operand instructions? Like ADD would pop twice, add two values, then push the sum. That's what I was thinking for a hypothetical stack machine I wanted to simulate.

The 432 is apparently not a pure stack machine, though it has stack instructions. The code structure is such that a stack-based 'add' instruction would require a class value (4 bits), format bits to say all stack operands (4 bits), and some opcode bits (4 bits)
